# How to make string accessible to a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to save the sting i get from selecting a row to be used in a button protected void.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string = id <= how to get the string here?
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    string id = row.Cells[3].Text;
}
```

Comment: How many rows can be selected at a time? Do you really need to separate the selection of the row from the button click event? Could you perhaps put the button inside the row itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code that gets the id to a property, e.g.:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = SelectedId;
}

private string SelectedId 
{
  get
  {
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    return row?.Cells[3].Text; // Please note the check against null (row?)
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, select row does not get recognized when i select  a row?

Comment: @JakeMogensen in a test project, I was able to get the id with the code. What do you mean by "not recognized"? Is row `null`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be:

Set Button2 to be disabled at start and...

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
}

// only allow the button to be enabled if there is a selected row
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (GridView1.SelectedRow != null){
        Button2.Enabled = true;
    } else {
        Button2.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of initializing String inside the function, Use session, it'll store your value and you can access it anywhere in the code.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblanything.Text = Session["id"].ToString();
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    Session["id"] = row.Cells[3].Text;
}
```

Hope it'll resolve your issue.

Comment: Works kinda, but button1_click with Label1.Text = id; makes the label empty?

Comment: Can you fix it?

Comment: That's not a "global". You just made it a field of the class. And that field's value isn't going to persist across postbacks. Fields in Web Forms pages are usually a very bad idea.

Comment: You can use Session, let me update the answer. And it'll work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can save the string value in a Viewstate and then try to access the value.

```
//Setting the ViewState 
    protected void MyGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = MyGridView.SelectedRow;
        ViewState["id"] = row.Cells[3].Text;
    }

 //Assigning the ViewState 
    protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lable1.Text = ViewState["id"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Static variables are usually a bad idea in a web application, because all visitors see the same value!

Comment: Considering it as web application then  ViewState/Session can be used to save  value. ViewState["ClickedValue"] =row.Cells[3].Text; lable1.Text =ViewState["ClickedValue"];

Comment: If you're wanting to change your answer, then change your answer! Don't leave bad code in your question and better code in a comment.